# Is there a performance difference between head$filter and head$dropWhile with Haskell Strings?

Tags: performance, haskell, string-comparison

I'm working on lists of "People" objects in Haskell, and I was wondering if there was any difference in performance between `head$dropWhile` and `head$filter` to find the first person with a given name. The two options and a snip of the datatype would be:

```
datatype Person = Person { name :: String
                         , otherStuff :: StuffTypesAboutPerson }

findPerson :: String -> [Person] -> Person
findPerson n = head $ dropWhile (\p -> name p /= n)
findPerson n = head $ filter (\p -> name p == n)
```

My thought was, `filter` would have to compare the full length of `n` to the full length of every `name` until it finds the first one. I would think `dropWhile` would only need to compare the strings until the first non-matching `Char`. However, I know there is a ton of magic in Haskell, especially GHC. I would prefer to use the `filter` version, because I think it's more straight-forward to read. However, I was wondering if there actually is any performance difference? Even if it's negligible, I'm also interested from a curiosity standpoint at this point.

Edit: I know I also need to protect from errors with `Maybe`, etc, but I left that out to simplify the code example.

Comment: Well... did you measure it? Not sure what you're expecting us to do that you can't do yourself. Other than the comments on performance in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info), there's not much expertise that can be brought to bear here.

Comment: I wasn't sure if anyone knew an answer based on Haskell/GHC's behavior. I didn't notice any difference by eyeballing it, and I'm not sure how to benchmark in Haskell.

Comment: [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) is good.

Comment: Would like to point out that you really just want `find`.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! And thanks so much HTNW!!! There are so many built-in functions I'm constantly finding out about as I work with Haskell :)

Comment: However, even with `find`, that still brings up the same problem. It's just a safe way of doing what `head$filter` does, isn't it?

Comment: All these approaches do essentially the same thing. Their performance differences, if any, should be negligible, and likely hard to detect. You are correct when you say that `==` on strings must scan all the strings _when they are equal_, and `/=` can terminate early _when they are different_. However, the vice versa also holds! `==` is not really more efficient than '/=` on strings, on the same inputs.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, use `Text` instead of `String` and a container other than `[]` to store the `Person`s.

Comment: Thanks @chi! If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to the problem

```
findPerson n = head $ dropWhile (\p -> name p /= n)
findPerson n = head $ filter (\p -> name p == n)
findPerson n = fromJust $ find (\p -> name p == n)
```

The question also points out two facts:

- when `x,y` are equal strings, `==` needs to compare all the characters
- when `x,y` are different strings, `/=` only needs to compare until the first different character

This is correct, but does not consider the other cases

- when `x,y` are equal strings, `/=` needs to compare all the characters
- when `x,y` are different strings, `==` only needs to compare until the first different character

So, between `==` and `/=` there is no performance winner. We can expect that, at most, one of them will perform an additional `not` w.r.t. the other one.

Also, *all* the three implementations of `findPerson` mentioned above, essentially perform the same steps. Given `xs :: [Person]`, they will all scan `xs` until a matching name is found, and no more. On all the persons before the match, the name will be compared against `n`, and this comparison will stop at the first different character (no matter what comparison we use above). The matching person will have their name compared completely with `n` (again, in all cases).

Hence, the approaches are expected to run in the same time. There might be a very small difference between them, but it could be so small that it would be hard to detect. You can try to experiment with `criterion` and see what happens, if you wish.